# Need help identifying this set - craft with 2 propellers

Tags: set-identification

old set.

thank you in advance Pls let me know if you need additional information.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based solely on 2x2 brick with 45° slope in olive green (which is a rare part appearing only in 10 sets), this can be identified as part of set [70006-1 "Cragger's Command Ship"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70006-1):

[image: Set 70006]

(BTW I wouldn't call a 2013 set "old", as I own sets dated late 1970s)

Comment: Many many thanks Ivan.

Comment: You're welcome! However, it's customary here to "accept" an answer instead of thanking in a comment. See https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers